# Trouble collecting user inputs and storing them in vector

Tags: visual-c++, vector, runtime-error, sentinel

I was told that instead of using an array i could us a vector to hold user inputs. The benefits of using a vector would be not having to declare the number of elements that the vector will have and if you add a value to a vector that is already full, the vector will automatically increase its size. I would also like a sentinel to exit the input loop. However when i try to implement this i get a runtime error.

I think the error is in line 14 or line 17.

the error message is

Debug Assertion Failed

Program:
C:\Users\Grayson\source\repos\AddUp.exe
File:d:program files\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\vector
Line1733

Expression:vector subscript out of range

for information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    vector<int>userIn;
    int numElements;
    int index=0;
```

```
cout << "Enter your inputs. Enter -1 to quit." << endl;
```

```
    while (userIn[index] != -1)
    {
        cout << "Input index #" << index << ": " << endl;
        cin >> userIn[index];
        index++;
    }
```

```
cout << "done";

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add element to vector a wrong way.
Correct way is using 'push_back'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        vector<int>userIn;
        int elem;
        int index = 0;

        cout << "Enter your inputs. Enter -1 to quit." << endl;

        while (true)
        {
                cout << "Input index #" << index << ": ";
                cin >> elem;

                if (elem != -1)
                {
                        userIn.push_back(elem);
                        index++;
                }
                else
                {
                        break;
                }
        }

        cout << "done";

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what you asked and i still have the error.

Comment: Sory, I forgot about it's a vector. I have edited my answer

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you.